# JQuery UI Dialog Box Display Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I created a validation to check if a person is less than 18 years of age. If the person is less than 18 years of age a dialog box opens. I'm using JQuery UI dialog-box to do this, but the dialog-box looks messed up **(see picture)**. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. How do i make the dialog box display correctly?

```js
  function myFunction() {
   today = new Date();
   todayYear = today.getFullYear();
   todayMonth = today.getMonth();
   todayDay = today.getDay();
      var x = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
   birthDate = new Date(x);
   birthYear = birthDate.getFullYear();
   birthMonth = birthDate.getMonth();
   birthDay = birthDate.getDay();

   age = todayYear - birthYear;
   
   if (todayMonth < birthMonth - 1 ){
    age--;
   }
   
   
   if (age < 18){
    $( function() {
     $('<div></div>').dialog({
       modal: true,
       title: "Age Check?",
       open: function () {
      var markup = 'Applicant is not 18 years old. Do you wish to continue?';
      $(this).html(markup);
       },
       buttons: {
      'Confirm': function() {
         $(this).dialog('close');
      },
      'Change': function() {
         $('#DOB').val('');
         $(this).dialog('close');
      }
       }
     });
      } );  
    
   }
  }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input name="DOB" onchange="myFunction()" type="date" class="form-control" id="DOB" required style=Width:60%; position:relative; placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

[image]

Comment: Your datepicker don't even work. if you import `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` then you don't need to import `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` second time. anyways, did you want to open a modal dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery-ui.css` is missing

```js
function myFunction() {
   today = new Date();
   todayYear = today.getFullYear();
   todayMonth = today.getMonth();
   todayDay = today.getDay();
      var x = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
   birthDate = new Date(x);
   birthYear = birthDate.getFullYear();
   birthMonth = birthDate.getMonth();
   birthDay = birthDate.getDay();

   age = todayYear - birthYear;
   
   if (todayMonth < birthMonth - 1 ){
    age--;
   }
   
   
   if (age < 18){
    $( function() {
     $('<div></div>').dialog({
       modal: true,
       title: "Age Check?",
       open: function () {
      var markup = 'Applicant is not 18 years old. Do you wish to continue?';
      $(this).html(markup);
       },
       buttons: {
      'Confirm': function() {
         $(this).dialog('close');
      },
      'Change': function() {
         $('#DOB').val('');
         $(this).dialog('close');
      }
       }
     });
      } );  
    
   }
  }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input name="DOB" onchange="javascript:myFunction()" type="date" class="form-control" id="DOB" required style=Width:60%; position:relative; placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

Comment: Do you know why the code works online for example, if i use Jfiddle i see the dialog-box and validation works properly. But the same code i open it  locally it doesn't work. I cant even see the dialog-box show up.

Comment: just include `jquery-ui.css`. Check `html` of [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/a5zsx9we/#&togetherjs=9O7ylGxqpv)

Comment: locally it was complaining about adding the extra https:// in the beginning of  the references. Thanks this worked.